# Please correct the typo on tag name ssis-data-tranformations

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Please change the tag name [ssis-data-tranformations](/questions/tagged/ssis-data-tranformations) to [ssis-data-transformations](/questions/tagged/ssis-data-transformations)

The letter **s** is missing in the word tran`s`formations.

Is there any other way to submit a tag rename request? Sorry, I searched but couldn't find a option other than to submit here at meta.

[image: ssis-data-tranformation]